# Client Server No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' when returning json from own domain

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, angularjs, linkedin-api

I have an application using angular/js on the frontend and a php backend. Both are using the same domain (www.foo.bar).

I have implemented linkedin authentication on my backend. So in the frontend I do something like

```
     $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://foo.bar/api/authenticate',
            headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).success(function(outcome){
            console.log("success");
        }).error(function(outcome){
            console.log('error');
        });
```

My server then authenticates the user with linkedin (this includes some redirects) and finally returns a json containing basic profile information retrieved from linkedin.

If I access my api directly: foo.bar/api/authenticate, it works like a charm and I get to see the json. If I call it using an ajax request on my frontend, I get the

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?blablabla No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://foo.bar' is therefore not allowed access.
```

exception.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
After looking at the possible sollutions I narrowed down the issue and more or less fixed it.
The problem is not that I cannot access the json files from my own api, the problem is that I do a redirect in the ajax call.

```
public function authorize(){
    return Redirect::away("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=linkedinApiData&redirect_uri=http://foo.bar/api/members/authenticated");
}
```

I was thinking that if this redirects to another api call, that finishes the authorization and returns a json object, that it would be okay, but then I get the exception mentioned before (coming from linkedin I guess).

I have a temporary solution by just using a
http://foo.bar/api/..>, which processes the auth request, does the redirect and finally redirects to the page I have to go and stores the result json in a session.
When the next page loads I ask the backend to return the contents of this session.

Is it possible to do a post, with authentication (that contains a redirect, needed for linkedin auth) and then returning the json from my own server (which works and does not have the access header problems?

Answer (score 1):

The domain is only a part of the origin. The entire origin:

- Scheme
- Complete hostname
- Port

… has to match.

`foo.bar` is not the same as `www.foo.bar`.

Either be consistent about which hostname you are using (in general, redirecting all requests from `example.com` to `www.example.com` or vice versa is a good idea) or implement one of the means to [circumvent the same origin policy](/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy).

Answer (score 0):

You must add Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in your http://foo.bar/api/authenticate service.

Sample;

```
<?php
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header("access-control-allow-origin: *"); 
?>
```

If you want to set for a specitic domain you must change * section to http://www.foo.bar or www.foo.bar